# How to renumber a partition?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I used to have a primary partition, `/dev/sdb1`, and an extended partition, `/dev/sdb2`. Since I deleted `sdb1` and merged it into `sdb2`, I’ve been trying to think of a way to modify the id `'/dev/sdb2'` to `'/dev/sdb1'` (beacuse there won’t be `/dev/sdb1` anymore).

There’s also two logical partitions inside `/dev/sdb2`: `/dev/sdb5` and `/dev/sdb6`.

Is there an easy way to modify the numeric id?

My partition table looks like this:

```
Device Boot     Start        End     Blocks  Id  System
----------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdb2        2048  234440703  117219328   f  W95 Ext’d (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       16065   87249014   43616475   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6    87251063  234440703  73594820+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Nr  AF  Hd  Sec  Cly   Hd  Sec   Cly  Start       Size  ID
----------------------------------------------------------
 1  00   0    0    0    0    0     0      0          0  00
 2  00  32   33    0  254   63  1023   2048  234438656  0f
 3  00   0    0    0    0    0     0      0          0  00
 4  00   0    0    0    0    0     0      0          0  00
 5  00   0    1    1  254   63  1023  14017   87232950  07
 6  00  32   33  311  254   63  1023   2048  147189641  07
```

Comment: Why?  There's nothing wrong with not having a partition 1.

Comment: I know. But I feel that the thing may be done simply in some way, I just don't know how.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Delete the partitions, and recreate them in exactly the same positions.  Make sure you are using sectors as the unit to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: Can we agree that suggesting to destroy even potentially very large partitions full of useful data, when there is a solution that with one command, 5 steps and 2 minutes of total time achieves the same result, is total nonsense?

Answer (score 16):

To fix partitons order, enter fdisk with root privileges

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

enter "extra functionality (experts only)"

```
> x
```

fix partition order

```
> f
```

then return to main menu

```
> r
```

preview & check new partiton "order"

```
> p
```

write table to disk and exit

```
> w
```

in any menu list available commands at the time (for help)

```
> m
```

Comment: Suggest first command should be "$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb" rather than "$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb2" as the command works on the whole disk rather than a single partition.  With that modification your instructions are perfect.